# How to time bubble and insertion sorting?

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7

I'm trying to time the bubble and the insertion sorting. The sorting works fine for both of them, but it outputs that it takes 15 seconds, which is clearly incorrect. Any suggestions how to fix this?

```
# insertion sort
x = [7, 2, 3, 5, 9, 1]

def insertion(list):
    for index in range(1,len(list)):
        value = list[index]
        i = index - 1
        while i>=0 and (value < list[i]):
            list[i+1] = list[i] # shift number in slot i right to slot i+1
            list[i] = value # shift value left into slot i
            i = i - 1

# bubble sort
y = [7, 2, 3, 5, 9, 1]

def bubble(unsorted_list):
    length = len(unsorted_list) - 1
    sorted = False

    while not sorted:
        sorted = True
        for i in range(length):
            if unsorted_list[i] > unsorted_list[i+1]:
                sorted = False
                unsorted_list[i], unsorted_list[i+1] = unsorted_list[i+1], unsorted_list[i]

def test():
    bubble(y)
    insertion(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print(timeit.timeit("test()", setup="from __main__ import test"))
```

Comment: Suggestion: both `list` and `sorted` are the names of builtins -- `list` being the type, and `sorted` being a handy function which returns a sorted list.  You should try to avoid shadowing those with your own variables.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this, you capture the current time, execute the function and then subtract the previous captured time from the current time.

```
# insertion sort
x = [7, 2, 3, 5, 9, 1]

def insertion(list):
    for index in range(1,len(list)):
        value = list[index]
        i = index - 1
        while i>=0 and (value < list[i]):
            list[i+1] = list[i] # shift number in slot i right to slot i+1
            list[i] = value # shift value left into slot i
            i = i - 1

# bubble sort
y = [7, 2, 3, 5, 9, 1]

def bubble(unsorted_list):
    length = len(unsorted_list) - 1
    sorted = False

    while not sorted:
        sorted = True
        for i in range(length):
            if unsorted_list[i] > unsorted_list[i+1]:
                sorted = False
                unsorted_list[i], unsorted_list[i+1] = unsorted_list[i+1], unsorted_list[i]

def test():
    start = time.clock()
    bubble(y)
    elapsed = (time.clock() - start)
    print "Time taken for bubble = ", elapsed
    start = time.clock()
    insertion(x)
    elapsed = (time.clock() - start)
    print "Time taken for Insertion = ", elapsed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    test()
```

Comment: `print "Time taken for Insertion = " + elapsed` should be `print "Time taken for Insertion = ", elapsed`. But it shows 0.0 for both of them.

Comment: edited the answer, check now, actually there are two methods in time module namely time() and clock(), time() has different behaviour in both windows and linux.

Answer (score 5):

From the [`timeit` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit):

> **timeit.timeit**(stmt='pass', setup='pass', timer=,
>   number=1000000)
>
> Create a Timer instance with the given statement,
>   setup code and timer function and run its timeit() method with number
>   executions.

So your code is running 1,000,000 times. Divide the return value by `10**6` and you'll be on your way.

Answer (score 0):

[profile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) is also an option you could consider.